# Need help adding Microdata to an event

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I'm struggling to correctly add microdata to events on my page. The [Google Structured Data Testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) can read the data but it isn't displaying it correctly.  I'm getting confused.

I am trying to tag it for a sports league that has a single event on one night that consists of three games all taking place at the same location.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent"><!--microdata week 1 event-->
<meta itemprop="name" content="Week 1 Lacrosse Games">
<meta itemprop="location" content="Street, Town, NY">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"> <!--column-->
<h3>Week 1<br><span itemprop="startDate" content="2014-06-27T18:00">Friday, June 27</span></h3>
<br>
<div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/subEvent">
<h4><span itemprop="name">Game 1</span> - 6:00 PM</h4>
<p><span itemprop="performer">Team 1 vs.Team 2</span></p>
</div>
<div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/subEvent">
<h4><span itemprop="name">Game 2</span> - 7:00 PM</h4>
<p><span itemprop="performer">Team 3 vs. Team 4</span></p>
</div>
<div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/subEvent">
<h4><span itemprop="name">Game 3</span> - 8:00 PM</h4>
<p><span itemprop="performer">Team 5 vs. Team 6</span></p>
</div>
</div><!--end column-->
</div><!--microdata week 1 event-->
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "isn't displaying it correctly"?

Comment: I didn't see your comment.  If you look at my response below, Google has a tool to test how the microdata will be displayed in search results.  It also tells you if it can be read or not.  It appears to be correctly understood, but in the "preview" section it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using subevents, Google required that I have the microdata URL called out for each event.  They have a rule that says if you have multiple events on the same page, you need to have a URL for each one.

Since I used the same page for all of them, I gave each subevent a unique ID and I linked that ID in the address.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what sort of problems you're having with the rich snippets displaying, but I did notice a couple of things that I'd recommend you change.  Since all of these events are sporting events, I would probably recommend that you use the SportsEvent type for them all.  You also need to specify all of the start times in ISO 8601 format.  Additionally, the expected value of the "performer" property is either an Organization or Person, and SportsTeam is an extension of the Organizaton type.  So I would recommend using that property twice within each event so that you could specify the two different teams that are playing, along with the SportsTeam type, like this:

```
<div itemprop="subEvent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
<h4><span itemprop="name">Game 1</span> - <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2014-06-27T18:00" />6:00 PM</h4>
<p><span itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
<span itemprop="name">Team 1</span></span> vs</p>
<p><span itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
<span itemprop="name">Team 2</span></span></p>
</div>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. The subevents now have separate performers.  It is easier to provide two links to show what I'm talking about.

Here is the [Data Tool with my page](http://www.yahoo.com/http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stlaxclub.com%2Fschedule).  It reads, no preview.  

Here is the [Data Tool with a working page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reverbnation.com%2Fpastywhitedoublewide).  It reads and displays a preview.